# How to add visual documentation to a method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, documentation

I want to add the following documentation to a method:

```
/*! @discussion
   Creates a new tab

           ___    ___
 _________| + |__| 1 |__
                        |
                 |      |
                710     |
                       748

 */
```

The problem is that when tab the method (pressing the Option key) all I get is:

[image]

As you can see all the drawing is get lost because line returns are not respected.
There is any way to save "drawings" on the documentation?

Comment: For the change of line, add a empty line (another carrier return). Next you issue is that the distance won't be the same (character width).

Answer (score 2):

ok, I realized how to add drawings on the documentation:
Just nest your "drawing" with @code and @endcode pragmas like this:

```
/*! @code
   Creates a new tab

           ___    ___
 _________| + |__| 1 |__
                        |
                 |      |
                710     |
                       748
 @endcode
```

Then, if you click your method(with Option key) you get the correct picture:

[image]